# Returning a value produced in Kotlin coroutine

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

I am trying to return a value generated from coroutine

```
fun nonSuspending (): MyType {
    launch(CommonPool) {
        suspendingFunctionThatReturnsMyValue()
    }
    //Do something to get the value out of coroutine context
    return somehowGetMyValue
}
```

I have come up with the following solution (not very safe!):

```
fun nonSuspending (): MyType {
    val deferred = async(CommonPool) {
        suspendingFunctionThatReturnsMyValue()
    }
    while (deferred.isActive) Thread.sleep(1)
    return deferred.getCompleted()
}
```

I also thought about using event bus, but is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do

```
val result = runBlocking(CommonPool) {
    suspendingFunctionThatReturnsMyValue()
}
```

to block until the result is available.

Comment: @Dmytro Danylyk I reverted your change. The `runBlocking` function was never removed and `withContext` does something completely different.

Comment: @KirillRakhman sorry I misread it, thought it was `run`. Btw, I think it's still better to use `withContext`. Documentation says: `runBlocking ` to be used in main functions and in tests. https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental/run-blocking.html

Comment: @DmytroDanylyk `withContext` is a `suspend` function. The code in question is inside a regular function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
private val uiContext: CoroutineContext = UI
private val bgContext: CoroutineContext = CommonPool

private fun loadData() = launch(uiContext) {
 try {
  val task = async(bgContext){dataProvider.loadData("task")}
  val result = task.await() //This is the data result
  }
}catch (e: UnsupportedOperationException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

 }
```