# Kotlin coroutines, is there a better way to return this value?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, coroutinescope

Struggling with coroutines, but is there a better way to use/get the value for a long running call out here before passing it onto another network coroutine with the callback? I've seen others but than i can't seem to use the value with the latest droid coroutine release, like I can't seem make this work [Kotlin Coroutines with returning value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055804/kotlin-coroutines-with-returning-value)

```
private suspend fun launchGeneratePayload(): String? { 
    return withContext (Dispatchers.Default) {
        try {
            val payloadString = slowStringGeneration()//Slow
            return@withContext payloadString
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            return@withContext null
        }
    }
}
```

Where the value is ultimately used

```
public someFunction(callback: CallBack) {      
    val params: JSONObject = JSONObject()
    params.put("param1", "param1Value")
    runBlocking{ //probably should be launch or similar
        val payload = launchGeneratePayload()
        params.put("param2", payload)
        //call network function with params & callback
        //networkCall (
    } 
}
```

Thanks for any help

edit: I think was actually looking for was just a bit different with

```
suspend fun launchGeneratePayload(): String? =
    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        try {
            slowStringGeneration() //slow
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
             null
        }
    }
}
```

Will add as an answer later incase i'm still off on this/else.

Comment: Use scoped coroutines and learn about suspend and await, you'll love it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `launch` coroutine builder to start the coroutine:

```
private var job: Job = Job()
private var scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)

fun someFunction(callback: CallBack) {
    val params: JSONObject = JSONObject()
    params.put("param1", "param1Value")
    scope.launch { // launch the coroutine
        val payload = generatePayload() // generate String without blocking the main thread
        params.put("param2", payload)
        //call network function with params & callback
        //networkCall (params, callback)
    }
}

suspend fun generatePayload(): String? = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    try {
        slowStringGeneration() //slow
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        null
    } 
}
```

Note: you can also make `networkCall()` as **suspend**, then you won't need to use `callback`.

To use `Dispatchers.Main` in Android add dependency to the app's build.gradle file

> implementation
>   'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'

Comment: So if whatever calls someFunction needs the result of onSuccess/onFail CallBack, someFunction needs to be suspend as well? With the same return type so i can chain it

Comment: I don't know what architecture you use for your app, but I would place `someFunction` in some Presenter or ViewModel and when `fun networkCall(params): Result` is called I would use some `Result` object to check whether it is failed or not. So it can be something like this: 
...
`val result = networkCall (params)
if (result.isSuccess) { call some UI function to notify about success }
else { call some UI function to notify about failure }`