# How to return response value from coroutine

Tags: android, class, kotlin, fragment, coroutine

I've recently work with Kotlin, and got really stuck with this one problem. I'm trying to return float value receive  onResponse of a coroutine api call function. I'm trying to create a class that handle api call and use it on a fragment.

**FunctionA.kt**

```
class FunctionA(val context: Context?, val A: Float?, val B: String?){

   private var cardApi: CardApi = ApiClient.createApi().create(CardApi::class.java)

   ....

   func getBalance(cardNo: String): Float?{
       val cardBalance: Float = null

       GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val cardDetails = cardApi.getCardBalance(cardNo)
            cardDetails.enqueue(object : Callback<Card> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Card>, t: Throwable) {
                    trackEvent(API_READ_CARD_BALANCE_ERROR, ERROR to t.message!!)
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Card>, response: Response<Card>) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        val card = response.body()!!
                        cardBalance = card.cardAvailableBalance

                    } else {
                        val error: ApiError = ErrorUtils.parseError(response)
                        val message = error.code + error.message
                        trackEvent(API_READ_CARD_BALANCE_ERROR, ERROR to message)
                        context!!.toast("Errror: " + message)

                        promptErrorDialog(error)
                    }
                }
            })
        }}

        return cardBalance
   }
   ....
   ....

}
```

**FragmentClass.kt**

```
class FragmentClass : BaseFragment(){

    val galA = 10.5f
    val galB = "Test"
    private var pass = FunctionA(context!!, valA ,valB)

    ....

    val point = "sasd12125"
    private fun gooToo(){
        val B = pass.getBalance(point)
        print("TEST")
        println("value B: " + B)
    }
    ....

}
```

What happend right now, since the coroutine will take some time in background, `val B` are null and didn't get the value obtained onResponse. Only after I try to call that functionA again, then the value are updated. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right and I've tried to search for solutions, but it doesn't suit with my current situation. Probably my searching skill are soo bad.

**Output**

```
TEST
value B: null
```

How should I wait for the coroutine to finish before return the `cardBalance` value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin Coroutines with returning value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055804/kotlin-coroutines-with-returning-value)

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi sorry for the late reply. That answer did not help with my particular problem. But I found a solution that handle my problem. I end up using a callback to pass the response. I will update my question the solution that works. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: That's okay, generally if you need to return a result from a coroutine you should use async function which returns a Deferred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve my little problem I end up using a callback to pass the response data. I found that this method work perfectly and easier to understand for my level of understanding. This method skeleton can also be reused for any api service call that I want to use in the future.

**FunctionA.kt**

```
class FunctionA(val context: Context?, val A: Float?, val B: String?){

   private var cardApi: CardApi = ApiClient.createApi().create(CardApi::class.java)
   private var card: Card? = null

   interface CardBalanceCallback {
       fun processFinish(output: Boolean, cardBalance: Float?)
   }

   fun getCardBalance(cardNo: String, callback: CardBalanceCallback) = runBlocking {
       getBalance(cardNo, callback)
   }

   private fun getBalance(cardNo: String, callback: CardBalanceCallback) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        try {
            val response = cardApi.getCardBalance(cardNo).await()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                card = response.body()
                callback.processFinish(true, card!!.cardAvailableBalance)
            } else {
                callback.processFinish(false, null)
                val error: ApiError = ErrorUtils.parseError(response)
                val message = when {
                    error.error.code.isNotEmpty() -> error.error.code + error.error.message
                    else -> error.code + error.message
                }
                trackEvent(API_READ_CARD_BALANCE_ERROR, ERROR to message)
                promptErrorDialog(error)
            }
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            callback.processFinish(false, null)
            trackEvent(API_READ_CARD_BALANCE_ERROR, ERROR to e.message!!)
            context!!.toast(e.message.toString())
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            callback.processFinish(false, null)
            trackEvent(API_READ_CARD_BALANCE_ERROR, ERROR to e.message!!)
            context!!.toast( e.message.toString())
        }
    }
   ....
   ....

}
```

**FragmentClass.kt**

```
class FragmentClass : BaseFragment(){

    private var funcService = FunctionA(null, null ,null)

    ....

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        (activity!!.application as App).component.inject(this)

        val valA = 10.5f
        val valB = "Test"
        val cardNo = "4001526976443264"
        val cardExpDate = "1119"

        funcService = FunctionA(context!!, valA ,valB)
        getCardBalanceApi(cardNo, cardExpDate)

    }

    .... 

    private fun getCardBalanceApi(cardNo: String, cardExpDate: String?) {
        showLoadingDialog()
        funcService.getCardBalance(cardNo, object : SmartPayService.CardBalanceCallback {
            override fun processFinish(output: Boolean, cardBalance: Float?) {
                dismissLoadingDialog()
                if (cardBalance != null) {
                    checkBalance(cardNo, cardBalance, cardExpDate)
                }
            }
        })
    }

    ....

}
```

This is some simple changes that I made for this particular problem on my first post. This approach might not be as good or smooth enough as I'm still learning. Hope it help some of you guys. cheers

Comment: So, you ended up not using Kotlin coroutines at all, although your question was about coroutines in particular 

Comment:  yeaa I guess, I was doing it the wrong way initially. Should I edit my question to something more relevant? I'm not too sure on the right question to ask for this. any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Proper way to return a single value from a coroutine is to use `await()`.

Now, since you use coroutine to wrap some callback API, that wouldn't work so well. So I would suggest to go with something like this:

```
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

suspend fun getBalance(cardNo: String): Float{
    val res = CompletableDeferred<Float>()

    scope.launch {
        val cardDetails = cardApi.getCardBalance(cardNo)
        cardDetails.enqueue(object : Callback<Card> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Card>, t: Throwable) {
                trackEvent(API_READ_CARD_BALANCE_ERROR, ERROR to t.message!!)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Card>, response: Response<Card>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val card = response.body()!!
                    res.complete(card.cardAvailableBalance)

                } else {
                    val error: ApiError = ErrorUtils.parseError(response)
                    val message = error.code + error.message
                    trackEvent(API_READ_CARD_BALANCE_ERROR, ERROR to message)
                    res.completeExceptionally(message)

                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        promptErrorDialog(error)    
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    return res.await()
}
```

A few points to consider. First, I used `Dispatchers.IO` instead of `Dispatchers.Main`, and switch to `Main` thread only when needed using `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)`. Otherwise, you're just running your IO on the main thread, coroutine or not.

Second, using `GlobalScope` is a bad practice, and you should avoid it at all cost. Instead I create a custom scope that you can `.cancel()` to prevent coroutine leak.

Third, the most correct way would be to return `Deferred<Float>`, and not `Float`, since `await()` is blocking. But I left it for simplicity.

Comment: Hi @Alexey Soshin , sorry for the late reply. At that time of the moment I was soo confused and had tried soo many things. And I took your advice on using `Deffered` instead for the call response since I use `.await()` . thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Make `getBalance()` a suspend function and then call using `lifecycleScope` in your fragment

```
private fun gooToo(){
   lifecycleScope.launch {
       val B = pass.getBalance(point)
       print("TEST")
       println("value B: " + B)
   }
}
```

`getBalance()` function signature would be something like

```
suspend fun getBalance(): Float = withContext(Dispatchers.IO)
```